# Project type for Windows Phone 8.1 game in VS 2013

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, xna, visual-studio-2013, game-engine

I would like to develop a game for the Windows Phone 8.1 platform but I cannot find the project type for game development in VS 2013.

I downloaded  the Windows Phone 8.1 development tools from http://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk. The New Project window in VS 2013 presents three project types for Store Apps ( Universal Apps, Windows Apps and Window Phone Apps ). None of the templates in each store apps is explicitly saying that it is for game development.

I watched a couple of videos and most are out-of-date and use VS 2010 or VS 2012 with XNA. There are some tutorials to install XNA in VS 2013 but I do not want to do this as it seems that XNA is dead. I would like to use the current tools available for VS 2013.

What tools and project templates is Microsoft providing for WP game development in VS 2013?

Comment: I would highly recommend SharpDX for your needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XNA Game Studio does not support Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 0):

You should have the option under Visual C# - > XNA Game Studio 4.0

[image]

You can get the full explanation on how to create your first Windows Phone 8 game with XNA in the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff472340%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).